# How to show $k$-algebras are isomorphic in practice

Tags: abstract-algebra, intuition, algebras

I am working through some problems which require me to show when some $k$-algebra ($k$ a field) maps are isomorphisms.  Unfortunately, I've got myself a bit confused with definitions and the like, and I don't quite know how to show when two $k$-algebras are isomorphic in practice.

Here's my definition:
Let $A$ and $B$ be $k$-algebras with respective structure maps $a: k \rightarrow A$, $b: k \rightarrow B$.  A $k$-algebra isomorphism is a ring isomorphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ s.t. $f \circ a = b$.

So, does this mean that, in practice, if I'm given a well-defined map $f$ from between two $k$-algebras, all I have to show is that it's a ring isomorphism?  Or is there a more subtle point that requires checking?

---

Some examples of the maps I'm trying to show are $k$-algebra isomorphisms:

1)  $f : M_n(k) \otimes_k A \rightarrow M_n(A)$, where $(x_{ij}) \otimes a \mapsto (ax_{ij})$.  (Here, $A$ is any $k$-algebra).

2)  $g:  A \otimes_k k[X] \rightarrow A[X]$, where $a \otimes \sum r_i T^i \mapsto \sum r_i a T^i $.  (Again, $A$ is any $k$-algebra)

---

If someone could explain how to go about explicitly showing when a map is a $k$-algebra isomorphism / demonstrate with one of those examples, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1 need not be an isomorphism and for 2 there are issues with commutativity.

Comment: I have replaced 1 with the closest thing that is correct. OP, is this what you meant?

Comment: 2 is correct if you define $A[X]$ appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @darijgrinberg , that was a typo on behalf.

Comment: I have been told that these maps are definitely $k$-algebra isomorphisms, and the task is to verify that they are explicitly.

Comment: 1) Try constructing an inverse: $(a_{ij}) \mapsto \sum_{i,j} E_{i,j} \otimes a_{ij}$ where $E_{i,j}$ is the appropriate elementary matrix. Can you see the similar construction that works for 2) ?

Comment: I can see the reasoning behind how to do 1), but I can't see a similar construction that would work for 2).  Any potential 'inverse' I can think of doesn't give the identity map when composed with the original map, so they cannot be right.